# How force PUT request from a POST with Spring?

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, unity-game-engine

I have a service with routes on PUT and I want to make a SDK implementing those routes in Unity3D. The problem is WWW don't accept PUT request.

The service is based on Spring Framework.

From the SDK, I try to call the route in POST with an additional parameter _method set to PUT but it doesn't work.

There is a way to simulate a PUT request with a POST call in Spring Framework?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you configured HiddenHttpMethodFilter filter in your springframework, its required at server side to convert post request with _method parameter to put request